# Convert a date to a string, concatenate the string and reconvert into date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to convert :

```
select  convert(nvarchar(16), TimeLog, 120) requestTime,
        count(Request) As noOfQueries 
from    LogData 

where  TimeLog  between @StartDate and @EndDate

group by convert(nvarchar(16), TimeLog, 120) order by requestTime;
```

Here in the where clause the `Timelog` is between: `2012-06-21` and `2012-06-21` but I want it between `2012-06-21 00:00:00` and `2012-06-21 23:59:59`

Hence I want to convert the `@Satrtdate / @EndDate` into above format so I would like to append `00:00:00` to `@StartDate` and `23:59:59` to `@EndDate` .

Comment: nvarchar(16)? When is your date ever going to hold Unicode data?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you for your reply . The select statement is irrelevant . Please can you see the where clause only .

Comment: That's why it was a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is:

```
SELECT 
  requestDate = CONVERT(CHAR(10), TimeLog, 120), 
  noOfQueries = COUNT(Request)
WHERE TimeLog >= @StartDate 
AND TimeLog < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), TimeLog, 120)
ORDER BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), TimeLog, 120);
```

The reason you don't want to use `BETWEEN` is because its behavior will differ depending on the underlying data type. If it's `SMALLDATETIME`, you will round up, and get data from the next day. If it's `DATETIME2`, you could miss data between `23:59:59.0000000 and 23:59:59.9999999`. And even if you know the data type now, it could change after you publish your query. Who's going to go back and correct `23:59:59` to `23:59:00` or `23:59:59.9999999`? With an open-ended range, selecting everything before the *next* day at midnight, you'll never have to worry about it.

Please give these two articles a read:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: +1 - I agree (beat me to it), but could you maybe explain _why_ the OP should do it this way?